# Find all python packages in project

Tags: python, module, githooks

I want to write some `clean up` script to avoid unexpected Python imports.

For better understanding, I'll show you my use cases.

Sometimes we have a situation when our project folders contains:

```
...
my_project/custom.py
my_project/custom/__init__.py
...
```

If you try to import something:

```
from my_project.custom import some_func
```

it imports from custom directory instead of custom.py file.

I want to avoid such situation and add some hook for checks if there is no python file in parent directory of some python package(folder with **init**.py file).

The question is:
What is the easiest way to find all the Python packages in my project?(all directories with **init**.py file)

There are a lot of Python libraries like: `imp`, `modulefinder`, ..., but I'm not sure if they may just check if folder is python module using fullpath(without loading this package)

As a final result I want to do something like this:

```
import os
for folder, sub, files in os.walk('/my/project/root/path'):
    # not sure folder or sub, but it doesn't matter
    if is_python_module(folder):
        # do some stuff
```

It looks like I've found some solution:

```
for folder,  sub, file in os.walk(path):
    try:
        _, module, _ = imp.find_module(folder)
        print "Module: %s" % module
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

If there is better solutions, feel free to tell!

Comment: I know this is semantics, but a directory ("folder") containing modules and an `__init__.py` file is called a *package*.  Why do you want to avoid this situation, what is the problem with it?

Comment: @cdarke, I want to avoid this situation, because if in your first implementation you have custom.py file and don't have custom package yet, all of your imports are importing from custom.py file. If you'll add custom folder(package), all of your old imports will have unexpected behaviour

Comment: So don't add a custom package of the same name.  Sorry to sound flippant.  Name collisions are not just reserved to module/package names - who knows the number of posts on this site where someone has named their script the same as a standard library module, or given a "variable" the same name as a built-in function or class.  Yes it is an issue, but it is solved by good code and project management.

Comment: @cdarke, sure! So, this pre-commit hook will help us to improve quality of our architecture and code. It's just a double check

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you are confusing the terminology:

- a directory with an `__init__.py` file is called a *package*; `my_project/custom/` is a Python package
- modules are files that contain Python code; `my_project/custom.py` is a Python module

Secondly, I would make better use of `os.walk` - the following code is much clearer in its intentions imho:

```
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(some_dir):
    if '__init__.py' in filenames:
        # do stuff
```

EDIT: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The following code might be useful.  I wrote it to aid understanding undocumented legacy code that was using `import .... as ...` rather a lot.  It isn't directly associated with `__init__.py` issues, but the reporting might help.  All it does is to iterate through your local namespace.

First I create a module called "spection.py" (you can call it anything):

```
"""
Python 2 version
10.1.14

"""
import inspect
import sys
import re

def look():

    for name, val in sys._getframe(1).f_locals.items():

        if inspect.ismodule(val):

            fullnm = str(val)

            if not '(built-in)' in fullnm and \
               not __name__     in fullnm:
                m = re.search(r"'(.+)'.*'(.+)'", fullnm)
                module,path = m.groups()
                print "%-12s maps to %s" % (name, path)
```

Now, in the module you wish to test you add after the imports, probably in "main()" if you have one:

```
import spection
spection.look()
```

If the module is being loaded from a named `.py` file then you should get something like this:

```
custom       maps to myproject/custom.pyc
```

If the module is being run from `__init__.py` you will get something like this:

```
custom       maps to myproject/custom/__init__.pyc
```

The function should do this for all modules (except builtins) imported at the point you call `section.look()`.  The `.pyc` files are shown, it will be the `.py` file the first time that module is used.

Here is the code I used for testing:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('myproject')
import custom

import spection
spection.look()
```

Hope it helps.